# Autowiring BuildProperties bean from Gradle - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, autowired

I am trying to obtain the version in my Java application from the Gradle build file. I am following the instructions here;

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
        plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

project.version = '0.1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

springBoot  {
    buildInfo()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'ci-backend'
}

war {
   baseName = 'ci-backend'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time")

    compile("com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9")
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
 }
```

After building with gradle the `build-info.properties` file is present in build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties

In my `@RestController` I am trying to autowire the build properties bean

```
@Autowired
private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

I am getting the following error;

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 41 more
```

I would assume that the `BuildProperties` bean is automatically created when the build-info.properties is present. It does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @Autowired
private BuildProperties buildProperties; was working and instantiating, if "build-info" file was generated by dependency management framework.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem I had may have been different, but I landed here trying to google the solution, so I'll post this here in case anybody else runs into the same problem. My error message was:

`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' available`

It was only when trying to run within IntelliJ, not when run with gradle from the command line. (AND this is possibly specific to SpringBoot)

I just needed to set "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle" from within "Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle" which then got the "bootBuildInfo" task to run when building from the IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the repo that had this issue, so I won't be able to confirm what the original issue was. However having a few answers here will certainly help people facing this same issue.

Comment: I just copied the file `build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties` to `out/production/resources/META-INF/build-info.properties`.

Comment: Same for Maven.

Answer (score 21):

For a Maven project, in IntelliJ "Preferences...", under Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner, select the option "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven."

Comment: You may get unit tests being run every time you start your application if you select that option.

Answer (score 12):

**Your assumption is right, the `BuildProperties` bean is automatically created when the `META-INF/build-info.properties` is present**.

See the following autoconfiguration code in [`ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/968a637e50a67c4aa2ab2ecf70519851b9cd79b7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.java#L66)

```
@ConditionalOnResource(
    resources = {"${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}"}
)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean
public BuildProperties buildProperties() throws Exception {
    return new BuildProperties(this.loadFrom(this.properties.getBuild().getLocation(), "build"));
}
```

However, if the bean is still not available in your application context, try any of the following:

1. Make sure the `buildInfo` gradle task is properly configured, run `gradlew bootBuildInfo --debug` and verify the results
2. Check if your IDE output directory differs from gradle's build directory, for example intellij make use of the `out` directory (in my case the `build-info.properties` file was not present)
3. Upgrade your gradle plugin, perhaps you hit this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12266, where you can try to use the following hack if you don't want to wait for the patch to be released

   ```
   def removeBootBuildInfoWorkaround12266 = task(type: Delete, 'removeBootBuildInfoWorkaround12266') {
       delete new File(buildDir, 'resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties')
   }
   tasks.find { it.name == 'bootBuildInfo' }.dependsOn(removeBootBuildInfoWorkaround12266)
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the repo that had this issue, so I won't be able to confirm what the original issue was. However having a few answers here will certainly help people facing this same issue.

Comment: This answer concluded my half day of searching thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

You would need to configure Intelij to use Gradle Runner so it generates build.properties file in out folder. Enable *Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle* option in Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner tab.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I ran into it today and wanted to share an alternate solution. I was running tests from IntelliJ that live in a separate package (although you could add annotations to restrict this configuration from loading, then it could just live in the main package)

Example is in kotlin:

```
@Configuration
class IntegrationAppConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BuildProperties::class)
    fun buildProperties(): BuildProperties = BuildProperties(Properties()).also {
        logger.error("BuildProperties bean did not auto-load, creating mock BuildProperties")
    }
}
```

This allows you to keep running with IntelliJ if you like, without having to go through Gradle if you don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

Newest versions of Intellij do not have the path "Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Runner" anymore.

To achieve the same result go to "Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Gradle projects" and select Gradle at "Build and run using:".

Answer (score 2):

to add to @Mike Emery response, found the equivalent Java's code bellow:

```
@Bean @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BuildProperties.class)
BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    log.error("BuildProperties bean did not auto-load, creating it");
    return new BuildProperties(new Properties());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem, it was maven issue I upgraded my maven verion(3.3.9) and built in command prompt instead of building it in the IDE. I know this is something weird but YES this is what worked for me.

Comment: This is because, similar to what @Casper said, the build-info.properties is not built by IntelliJ.  When you mvn clean the project it is removed.

If someone knows how to get IntelliJ to build that it would be appreciated.

Comment: In Intellij, when editing a run configuration, I am able to add a Before launch Maven goal of `spring-boot:build-info`.  It's a bit of a pain to have to do to all configurations, and I suspect @izilotti solution would be a one-time thing

Answer (score 1):

When the issue with IDE, you can try this fix.

Go to `File -> Settings`

then go to option `"Build, Execution, Deployment"->Build Tools->Gradle->Runner`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following in `build.gradle` resolved this issue for me:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Comment: These lines are already included in the `build.gradle` in the question

Answer (score 0):

This step was already done by the author, but I found myself in the same error as the author and nothing helped. But this helped:

I solved it by adding this to build.gradle:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Comment: As said: the author already has this in his build file, but maybe my answer will help some people searching for answers on this question